# How can I calculate the shear modulus (Gxy) for the material of a composite laminate [10/-10/-10/10] using test data?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials, composite

I have the data from a tensile test including axial displacement, force, and strain, as well as E1, E2, Nu12, and Nu21 for the carbon fiber prepreg. I am trying to use this axial data to calculate Gxy for a 4-ply laminate with the angular orientations [10/-10/-10/10]. How can this be done.

I am confused since the Q matrices and Q bar matrices depend on Gxy so I don't know how to use those if we are solving for Gxy. Also, I do not have any data from the transverse directions, only in the direction of the applied load.

The test coupon I used was 12" long by 2" wide.